# Android Application Using Python

Tags: python

How do i make my android application using python.
Is there any way to make android application using python?

Comment: check if this will help you http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this [Tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/mo-python-sl4a-1/index.html) .

Android applications using Python and SL4A, Part 1: Set up your development environment

Comment: Last I checked, using SLA4 will let you make an app for yourself, but you won't be able to put it up on App market (Google Play)

Comment: @ chrisfs Why cant we put our app on Google play if we had used SLA4 ?